# How do I sort a list of dictionaries by last name of the dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I need to write a sort_contacts function that takes a dictionary of contacts as a parameter and returns a sorted list of those contacts, where each contact is a tuple.

The contacts dictionary that will be passed into the function has the contact name as its key, and the value is a tuple containing the phone number and email for the contact.

**contacts = {name: (phone, email), name: (phone, email), etc.}**

The sort_contacts function should then create a new, sorted (by last name) list of tuples representing all of the contact info (one tuple for each contact) that was in the dictionary. It should then return this list to the calling function.

For example, given a dictionary argument of:

```
    {("Horney, Karen": ("1-541-656-3010", "karen@psychoanalysis.com"),
    "Welles, Orson": ("1-312-720-8888", "orson@notlive.com"),
    "Freud, Anna": ("1-541-754-3010", "anna@psychoanalysis.com")}
```

sort_contacts should return this:

```
    [('Freud, Anna', '1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com'), 
    ('Horney, Karen', '1-541-656-3010', 'karen@psychoanalysis.com'), 
    ('Welles, Orson', '1-312-720-8888', 'orson@notlive.com')]**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add the `key` and `value` and `sort`:

```
>>> sorted((k,)+v for k, v in contacts.items())
[('Freud, Anna', '1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com'),
 ('Horney, Karen', '1-541-656-3010', 'karen@psychoanalysis.com'),
 ('Welles, Orson', '1-312-720-8888', 'orson@notlive.com')]
```

If you don't care about a nested tuple then you can simply:

```
>>> sorted(contacts.items())
[('Freud, Anna', ('1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com')),
 ('Horney, Karen', ('1-541-656-3010', 'karen@psychoanalysis.com')),
 ('Welles, Orson', ('1-312-720-8888', 'orson@notlive.com'))]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def sort_contacts(contacts):
    real_contacts=[]
    function_keys=contacts.keys()

    for key in sorted(function_keys):
        data = (key, contacts[key][0], contacts[key][1])
        real_contacts.append(data)

    return real_contacts
```